# Creating a semi border of circle with textview

Tags: android, android-custom-view, geometry

[image]

I want some thing like this image. The blue color on the border of the circle is custom and should increase/decrease as per the value in text view. I would like to have some ideas to implement it.

Comment: there are many libraries doing this. did you google it before posting?

Comment: I did .. Not able to find any

Comment: Use this : http://www.truiton.com/2013/06/android-circular-progress-bar-customization-tutorial/ It might helps you.

Comment: have a look on this - https://github.com/CardinalNow/Android-CircleProgressIndicator

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">
    <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="10" android:useLevel="false">

        <size android:width="100dip" android:height="100dip" />
        <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#4ab0da"
            android:endColor="#4ab0da"
            android:centerColor="#eee"
            android:angle="0"
            />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this [Circle Progress Indicator official blog](http://www.cardinalsolutions.com/blog/2014/11/android_circle_progr)

**Features**

- Increase or decrease progress changes
- Modifiable
- Ring width
- Ring background color
- Ring fill color
- Ring gradient

Comment: Not yet .. I will try by tmrw !! I guess